# bootstrap navigation links not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The links within my site's header/navigation aren't working for some reason. I think it has something to do with the CSS I am using but I have followed the code exactly like it is on Bootstrap's documentation site. Can someone help me fix this error?

You can view the full site here: http://kaybesee.com/mb

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1000" data-offset-bottom="200">
<div class="container">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logoTextRight.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="" id="navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-button"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="nav-button"><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-button"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
</div><!-- #nav-wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 4):

Believe this is related, you have a `e.preventDefault` on your `li` click `line 36` on your index. I don't really see a reason for that, but since your anchor is inside, the anchor click event never fires.

Remove e.preventDefault();

```
  $('ul.nav > li').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: This was precisely the reason

Answer (score 0):

You Should Match the Page ID with the Tab ID in the CSS . I think there is some bug with bootstrap nav class.
See this article for more information. http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa042307.htm .